# Возможности HTML

Tags: html

Можно ли средствами HTML отображать текстовую информацию, например в ячейке таблицы, с помощью указателя на файл с текстом?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по спецификации http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#edef-OBJECT можно вместо iframe использовать object, например:

```
<object type="text/html" data="file.html"></object>
```

Но в результате получится что-то типа iframe, касаемо совместимости между броузерами - непонятно.

Можно воспользоваться CSS свойством content:

```
<div style="content:url(file.html)"></div>
```

Но это опять-же со всеми броузерами по-разному

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я предполагал, что должны существовать объектно-ориентированные подходы к решению такой задачи. Обязательно поэкспериментирую и посмотрю на реакцию броузеров. Еще раз спасибо.